# Container shows grey box on release mode (flutter)

Tags: flutter

a grey box was displayed in the screen. It was not on debug mode.
Only when I changed to release mode, a grey box appears.

What caused this problem? and how do I have to change?

```
itemInfoWidget() {
  return  Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(Get.context!).size.height * 0.55,
    width: MediaQuery.of(Get.context!).size.width,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black38,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
          topRight: Radius.circular(30),
        ),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(offset: Offset(0, 0), blurRadius: 0, color: Colors.green),
        ]),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 18,
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 8,
              width: 130,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black38,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                    (30),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 18,
          ),
          //name
          Row(
            children: [
              Text(
                widget.itemInfo!.name!,
                maxLines: 2,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 25
                ),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              Obx(() => IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (itemDetailsController.isFavorite == true) {
                    //delete item from favorites
                    deleteItemFromFavoriteList();
                  } else {
                    //save item to user favorites
                    addItemToFavoriteList();
                  }
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  itemDetailsController.isFavorite
                      ? CupertinoIcons.bookmark_fill
                      : CupertinoIcons.bookmark,
                  color :  const Color(0xffffd400),
                  size: 25,
                ),
              )),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
          ),
          //rating + rating num, tags, price
          Row(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              //rating
              RatingBar.builder(
                initialRating: widget.itemInfo!.rating!,
                minRating: 1,
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                allowHalfRating: true,
                itemCount: 5,
                itemBuilder: (context, c) => const Icon(
                  Icons.star,
                  color: Colors.amber,
                ),
                onRatingUpdate: (updateRating) {},
                ignoreGestures: true,
                unratedColor: Colors.black87,
                itemSize: 20,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),

              // rating num
              Text(
                "(${widget.itemInfo!.rating})",
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  fontSize: 18,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          //tags
          Text(
            "카테고리: ${widget.itemInfo!.tags!.toString().replaceAll("[", "").replaceAll("]", "")}",
            maxLines: 2,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          //price
          Text(
            "포인트: ${widget.itemInfo!.price!}",
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03,
          ),
          //모양, 색깔, 재질 박스
          // 1줄 넘어가면 재질 박스가 밑으로 이동하도록지(2 rows)
          // 1줄 안에 다 들어가면 1 row 유지하는 방법..?
          Center(
            child: Wrap(
              // 20221229
              alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
              spacing: 7,
              runSpacing: 8,
              children: [
                //색깔 박스
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      "색깔",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize:
                        16,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 2),
                    ...List.generate(widget.itemInfo!.colors!.length,
                            (index) {
                          return Container(
                            // height: 35,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 4, horizontal: 8),
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2),
                            // width: widget.itemInfo!.colors![index]
                            //             .replaceAll("[", "")
                            //             .replaceAll("]", "") ==
                            //         '얼룩덜룩한'
                            //     ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.26
                            //     : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15,
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                  offset: Offset(1, 1),
                                  blurRadius: 2,
                                  color: Colors.black38),
                            ], color: Color(0xff073215)),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text(
                              widget.itemInfo!.colors![index]
                                  .replaceAll("[", "")
                                  .replaceAll("]", ""),
                              maxLines: 2,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                    const SizedBox(width: 3),
                  ],
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      "모양",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 2),
                    ...List.generate(widget.itemInfo!.shapes!.length,
                            (index) {
                          return Container(
                            // height: 35,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 4, horizontal: 8),
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2),
                            // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15,
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                  offset: Offset(1, 1),
                                  blurRadius: 2,
                                  color: Colors.black38),
                            ], color: Color(0xff073215)),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text(
                              widget.itemInfo!.shapes![index]
                                  .replaceAll("[", "")
                                  .replaceAll("]", ""),
                              maxLines: 1,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                    const SizedBox(width: 2),
                  ],
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                Wrap(children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        "재질",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 2),
                      ...List.generate(widget.itemInfo!.materials!.length,
                              (index) {
                            return Container(
                              // height: 35,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 4, horizontal: 8),
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2),
                              // width:  widget.itemInfo!.materials![index]
                              //                 .replaceAll("[", "")
                              //                 .replaceAll("]", "") ==
                              //             '깍지벌레' ||
                              //         widget.itemInfo!.materials![index]
                              //                 .replaceAll("[", "")
                              //                 .replaceAll("]", "") ==
                              //             '거미줄'
                              //     ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.23
                              //     : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15,
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                    offset: Offset(1, 1),
                                    blurRadius: 2,
                                    color: Colors.black38),
                              ], color: Color(0xff073215)),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text(
                                widget.itemInfo!.materials![index]
                                    .replaceAll("[", "")
                                    .replaceAll("]", ""),
                                maxLines: 1,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),

                    ],
                  ),
                ]),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
          ),
          //description
          const Text(
            "특징: ",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.005,
          ),
          Text(
            widget.itemInfo!.description!,
            textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              color: Colors.white70,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.035,
          ),
          //관찰 올리기 - 버튼
          Material(
            elevation: 4,
            color: const Color(0xffBF5F27),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Get.to(() => UserUploadReviewsScreen(
                  itemInfo: widget.itemInfo,
                ));
              },
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                height: 50,

                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: const [
                    Icon(
                      CupertinoIcons.camera_fill,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 15,
                    ),
                    Text("관찰 올리기",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.035,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I want to show the contents not a grey box.

Comment: The reason it only appears in Release mode is since you have some kind of error, fix that error and it should be all good

Comment: You'll have to say error occured during debug mode, we might be of some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have commented, if you see a grey box in release mode, this means that you have some kind of **error**.

You should be able to view the error when running in *debug* mode and view the error in your console to correctly debug it. The error would be in red.

This can be any type of error, but for me, it was when I used an `Expanded` widget in the wrong place, I thought that I can just ignore it, but then in release mode, I had a white screen.

##### See also

[Explain that a grey screen on release is indicative of an error (and how to find the error)](https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/7773#issuecomment-1312087173).

Comment: I used Spacer. Would that  cause an error?

Comment: @theriaca01 Possibly... You'll have to run in debug mode and view the traceback.

Comment: Thank you! I found it! It was the usage of spacer. There are two spacers in a row in the container. I found no problem in usage of one spacer. But when I used two spacers, there is an error. so I deleted all spacers.