# In my Flutter app, Widget has problem and Gray screen appears

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a mobile application with Flutter. I coded a screen like this:

[image]

When I open this on my real phone, the screen looks like this:

[image]

Why so? I would be glad if you help. Codes:

```
class PersonDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PersonDetailPage({super.key});
  @override
  State<PersonDetailPage> createState() => _PersonDetailPageState();
}

FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
FirebaseAuth userDB = FirebaseAuth.instance;

class _PersonDetailPageState extends State<PersonDetailPage> {
  late Stream<DocumentSnapshot> _personStream;
  String personId = "";
  String personNameSurname = "";
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    personId = Get.arguments[0];
    personNameSurname = Get.arguments[1];
    _personStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(personId)
        .snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: textColorBlack,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Get.back();
          },
        ),
        title: Text(
          (personNameSurname).length > 20
              ? '($personNameSurname).substring(0, 20)}...'
              : personNameSurname,
          style: const TextStyle(color: textColorBlack),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.delete,
              color: deepRed,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              deletePerson(context);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: _personStream,
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          final Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          final Person person = Person.fromJson(data);
          return Stack(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: FlutterMap(
                  options: MapOptions(
                    center: LatLng(person.location!.latitude, person.location!.longitude),
                    zoom: 9.2,
                  ),
                  children: [
                    TileLayer(
                      urlTemplate:
                          'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                      userAgentPackageName: 'tree.disaster.app',
                    ),
                    MarkerLayer(
                      markers: [
                        Marker(
                          point: LatLng(person.location!.latitude, person.location!.longitude),
                          width: 80,
                          height: 80,
                          builder: (context) => const Icon(
                            Icons.location_history_rounded,
                            size: 50,
                            color: lightRed,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15, left: 10, right: 10),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(width: 20),
                        ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                          child: Image.network(
                            person.photo!,
                            width: 120,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 15),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "${person.name} ${person.surname}",
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5),
                            Text(
                              "Enlem: ${person.location!.longitude}\nBoylam: ${person.location!.longitude}",
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void deletePerson(BuildContext context) {
    Get.defaultDialog(
      titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      title: "Emin misiniz?",
      content: Text(
        "$personNameSurname isimli hesap, kişilerinizden silinecek. Onaylıyor musunuz?",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      confirm: TextButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          var getData = await db
              .collection("users")
              .doc(userDB.currentUser!.uid)
              .get();
          var getPersons = getData.data()!["Persons"] as List;
          getPersons.remove(personId);
          List newPersons = getPersons;
          await db
              .collection("users")
              .doc(userDB.currentUser!.uid)
              .update(
            {"Persons": newPersons},
          );
          Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
        },
        child: const Text(
          "Evet",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFF67BAFF),
            fontFamily: "Roboto Bold",
            fontSize: 18,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      cancel: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Get.back();
        },
        child: const Text(
          "Hayır",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFF4A4A4A),
            fontSize: 18,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget InfoCard(String title, String info) {
  return SizedBox(
    height: 60,
    child: Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(width: 12),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                color: backgroundGrey,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      title,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 10),
          Text(
            info.toString(),
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I have no idea why this is so. I had a similar problem before. It was solved by wrapping it with the Flexible widget, but this time I couldn't. How can I solve it? Thanks in advance for the help.

---

Error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type StackParentData.

Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a Stack widget.

The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
  LayoutBuilder ← FlutterMap ← Expanded ← Stack ← StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>> ← KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#4a56a] ← _BodyBuilder ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ← ⋯
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData.<anonymous closure>
#1      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData
#2      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject
#3      RenderObjectElement.mount
#4      _LayoutBuilderElement.mount
...     Normal element mounting (15 frames)
#19     Element.inflateWidget
#20     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
#21     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
#22     Element.inflateWidget
#23     Element.updateChild
#24     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#25     StatefulElement.performRebuild
#26     Element.rebuild
#27     BuildOwner.buildScope
#28     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
#29     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
#30     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
#31     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
#32     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
#33     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:145:13)
#34     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:338:5)
#35     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:112:31)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
D/EGL_emulation( 5159): app_time_stats: avg=34.86ms min=1.85ms max=500.43ms count=24
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Container shows grey box on release mode (flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74972835/container-shows-grey-box-on-release-mode-flutter)

Comment: @MendelG hello, no answers.

Comment: @WoAiNii I've added the error it gives to the console.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the Expanded Widget inside the Stack Widget which is creating the issue here.
To fix this you can Replace the Expanded Widget with the 'Positioned.fill' Widget which will provide the expected output without any error.
You can replace you widget with the below widget:

```
     Positioned.fill(
                  child: FlutterMap(
                    options: MapOptions(
                      center: LatLng(person.location!.latitude,
                          person.location!.longitude),
                      zoom: 9.2,
                    ),
                    children: [
                      TileLayer(
                        urlTemplate:
                            'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                        userAgentPackageName: 'tree.disaster.app',
                      ),
                      MarkerLayer(
                        markers: [
                          Marker(
                            point: LatLng(person.location!.latitude,
                                person.location!.longitude),
                            width: 80,
                            height: 80,
                            builder: (context) => const Icon(
                              Icons.location_history_rounded,
                              size: 50,
                              color: lightRed,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```