# Flutter: App stuck on white screen after converting to APK

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build.gradle

After converting my Flutter app to APK it's stuck on a white screen after installing it on a phone. It works fine in debug mode. I have no idea why or how to solve it. Any ideas? Here below you'll see the **main.dart** code.

**main.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:athena/providers/app_state.dart';
import 'package:athena/providers/user.dart';
import 'package:athena/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:athena/screens/splash.dart';
import 'locators/service_locator.dart';
import 'screens/home.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  setupLocator();
  return runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider<AppStateProvider>.value(
        value: AppStateProvider(),
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider>.value(
        value: UserProvider.initialize(),
      ),
    ],
    child: MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Athena',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UserProvider auth = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
    switch (auth.status) {
      case Status.Uninitialized:
        return Splash();
      case Status.Unauthenticated:
      case Status.Authenticating:
        return LoginScreen();
      case Status.Authenticated:
        return MyHomePage();
      default:
        return LoginScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Container shows grey box on release mode (flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74972835/container-shows-grey-box-on-release-mode-flutter)